# Using $_POST as a variable

Tags: php, post, get

Hello guys am a newbie to php .I am here to ask a question as usual.I have seen a code like this ..

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
case 'GET': $the_request = &$_GET; break;
case 'POST': $the_request = &$_POST; break;

.
. // etc.
.

default:
}
?>
```

My doubt is `$_get` here .As we know `s_get` is used to post the details of the variable to the server.But here `$_POST` is used as  a variable ..

My question is that can we use `$_POST` as a variable like `$_POST = $something`..

Am sorry if my question is not up to the standdard since am a newbie ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, $_POST its just an array.

Comment: so can we assign $_POST= $varibale ? and how can we call $varibale ? is it by calling $_POST ?

Comment: yes, you can assign $_POST = $variable 
and you can call it by $_POST.
the variable needs to be an array, and then you can use his keys.
$variable = array("stackoverflow","HELLO WORLD");
$_POST = $variable;
$_POST[0] // (will give you "stackoverflow")

Answer (score 1):

In PHP `$_POST` is a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array that is populated by data sent via the http post method.

You can manually add to the array, delete things from the array and manipulate it in any way you can manipulate other [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) in PHP.

See the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is normal array, visible in global scope ([see docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)). There's rather no  point of assigning its values to another array as in most cases there's no benefit from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

> As we know s_get is used to post the details of the varibale to the
>   server

Wrong. `$_GET` is used to grab the data that you have passed through the querystring of your URL.

> an we use $_POST as a variable like $_POST = $something..

Yes but not directly.. You could do this way..

```
<?php
$somevar = $_POST;
echo $somevar['name'] = 'John';//
```

Comment: Btw why are you using `$_GET` superglobal array for assigning ? Can't you use a normal array or a `$_SESSION` array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables as a normal array.. you can add values, assign values, alter, delete values from it.

There is no need to create a new array and assign values of `$_GET` or `$_POST` to it except in some special cases.